# not printing multiple checked boxes php

Tags: php, html

I have a loop that is supposed to print the selected checkboxes, but it only prints one item. If multiple are selected, it only prints the last line.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_courses'])){
//to run PHP script on submit
  if(!empty($_POST['boxes'])){
  // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
  foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $selected_course);
    echo "You have selected: " . $selected_course . "</br>";
  }
}
```

`$_POST['submit_courses']` is for if the submit button is pressed and `$_POST['boxes']` is for the boxes selected. `boxes[]` is the name of the input type for the checkboxes.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @mplungjan if I get rid of that if statement it still only outputs the last one selected

Comment: Change the `;` to `{` after the foreach `foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $selected_course) {
    echo "You have selected: " . $selected_course . "</br>";
  } `

Comment: @mplungjan I can't believe I put a semicolon after a for loop. How did I not notice that. I'm an idiot, thank you.

Comment: Please delete the question

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here

```
foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $selected_course);
    echo "You have selected: " . $selected_course . "</br>";
```

Change it using { } as below

```
foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $selected_course){
    echo "You have selected: " . $selected_course . "</br>";
}
```

Comment: You are correct. Yet another problem solved by a misplaced semi colon

Comment: @CaleighD the problem is that you don't use brackets `{}` and it will let you to get several mistakes along your career. Write code with a certain coding style and you'll avoid most typing errors.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['boxes'] Must be an array. You should check your html first and then look with print_r($_POST['boxes']) what is inside.